# Trying to dynamically generate _id in Mongoose, but returns object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Basically, I'm trying to count the documents in a collection, and set the new document to that as the _id. I've tried a number of combinations, but none of them seem to work.

Here's what I tried:

```
var count = PostModel.find( function( err, posts ) {
    if ( !err ) {
        return posts.length;
    }
    else {
        return console.log( err );
    }
});

var post = new PostModel({
    _id: count,
    title: request.body.title,
    content: request.body.content,
    tags: request.body.tags
});
```

Returns:

```
{ message: 'Cast to number failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'number',
  value:
   { options: { populate: {} },
     safe: undefined,
     _conditions: {},
     _updateArg: {},
     _fields: undefined,
     op: 'find',
     model:
      { [Function: model]
        modelName: 'Post',
        model: [Function: model],
        options: undefined,
        db: [Object],
        schema: [Object],
        collection: [Object],
        base: [Object] } },
  path: '_id' }
```

And this:

```
var post = new PostModel({
    _id: PostModel.find( function( err, posts ) {
        if ( !err ) {
            return posts.length;
        }
        else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
    }),
    title: request.body.title,
    content: request.body.content,
    tags: request.body.tags
});
```

Which returns the same error. However, when I add the following separately, it logs the length of the collection:

```
PostModel.find( function( err, posts ) {
    if ( !err ) {
        return console.log(posts.length);
    }
    else {
        return console.log( err );
    }
});
```

I tried using `count()` in various ways as well, but I wasn't able to make any headway. Any insight on how to query the collection for the count, and set that as the _id would be great helpful.

Comment: If you're trying to create an auto incrementing id for a collection, consider instead using one of these plug-ins: http://plugins.mongoosejs.com/?q=increment

Comment: You're link didn't work, but here's a plugin that you may or may not be referencing: https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-auto-increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is **not recommended** in MongoBD because it does not scale well.

But if you really want to do it, there are instructions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) in the official MongoDB docs for a nice and safe way to do it.

Basically you use a small document to hold the current sequence ID, and each time you insert a document you both read and increment that sequence atomically. It is a lot more efficient than counting the documents each and every time you insert.

With your solution, what happens if two processes are running at the same time? You will potentially end up with identical IDs because your insert and sequence generation/count are not atomic.

**Edit:**

To get the count from your model use the following:

```
PostModel.count( function (err, count) {
  if (err) ..
  console.log('there are %d posts', count);
});
```

**Edit by OP:**

Per the comments below, the issue was with using the asynchronous functions synchronously. When all of the code was moved to the callback functions, it worked. Here's the solution:

```
PostModel.count( function (err, count) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        console.log('there are %d posts', count);

        var post = new PostModel({
            _id: count,
            title: request.body.title,
            content: request.body.content,
            tags: request.body.tags
        });

        post.save( function( err ) {
            if( !err ) {
                return console.log( 'Post saved');
            } else {
                console.log( err );
            }
        });

        return response.send(post);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Scaling isn't really an issue because I'm just using Mongo to store my blog posts, so I'll only be inserting from one machine at a time and potentially reading from multiple machines. The link you sent me was definitely helpful, but I'm trying to figure out how to get this working in Mongoose. I'll see about adapting it, though I may have the same problems.

Comment: The key part to pull out is using a small document to store the sequence. From Mongoose you would do a `findAndModify` to get the current sequence and iterate it by one *atomically*.

Comment: Have a look at my update, hopefully it solves your counting problem

Comment: Also, in regards to scaling: Having a sequential _id can potentially affect your read times if you end up sharding your blog posts when you start to get many hits on your blog. For example you are likely to want to retrieve all the latest blogs which if using the _id as the shard key would result in all the queries coming to one machine, where if you used the hashed _id then the queries would be evenly distributed over all the shards.

Comment: All good advice. The above count returns the right count, but when I set it to a variable and passed the variable to the _id, it returned the same error, which makes it looks like the variable was an object, not a number. Also, if I set a different variable to a number and passed it to the _id, it worked fine. Not sure what's going on...

Comment: I don't know much about mongoose, but it looks like you are trying to use asynchronous callbacks in a synchronized way. Could you embed your `post = PostModel...` code inside the callback for the count function?